# .Net Dynamic table name in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, .net

How can I use a dynamic table name in the below SQL query?

```
"INSERT INTO `tableName` (`ADUC`, `DHCP`, `DISK`, `DNS`, `Exchange`, `HOSTNAME`, `HWID`, `IP`, `OS`) values (@aduc,@dhcp,@disk,@dns,@exchange,@hostname,@hwid,@ip,@os)"
```

Currently I am declaring `tableName` via

```
Dim tableName = My.Computer.Name.ToString
```

I want the table name to reflect the computers name as that's what I've created within PhpMyAdmin, so any thoughs on how to do this?

**Please note**:  that the  ``` `` ```needs to stay either side of the table name to support hyphenated table names in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO `"+tableName+"` (`ADUC`, `DHCP`, `DISK`, `DNS`, `Exchange`, `HOSTNAME`, `HWID`, `IP`, `OS`) values (@aduc,@dhcp,@disk,@dns,@exchange,@hostname,@hwid,@ip,@os)"
```

Comment: My god, it was that simple... Thank you m Hasan I will accept when it lets me.

Comment: Be careful that this method does not protect against SQL injection. If the `tableName` variable is provided externally (e.g. a user), the query can be manipulated into multiple queries, and any desired query may be performed on the database, including dropping all data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create store procedure like below and pass tablename and values as parameter because  you already know the table schema.

create table dynamictest

create table dynamictest(id varchar(max));

Now you need to insert value but table name is dynamic so you need to pass it.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[mssql_DynamicTableTest]
@LogTable VARCHAR(1024),
@code NVARCHAR(Max)


AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 

    @sql    NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @params NVARCHAR(Max);

SET @params = N'@LogTable VARCHAR(1024),@code NVARCHAR(Max)';

 SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO '+@LogTable+' VALUES ('''+@code+''')';
 select @sql;


  EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @LogTable,@code;



END
```

Now execute able store procedure by passing table name "dynamictest"  and value "test".